# Break nested loop in Django views.py with a function

Tags: python, django, loops, django-views

I have a nested loop that I would like to break out of. After searching this site it seems the best practice is to put the nested loop into a function and use return to break out of it. Is it acceptable to have functions inside the views.py file that are not a view? What is the best practice for the location of this function? Here's the example code from inside my views.py

```
@login_required
def save_bookmark(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookmarkSaveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            bookmark_list = Bookmark.objects.all()
            for bookmark in bookmark_list:
                for link in bookmark.link_set.all():
                    if link.url == form.cleaned_data['url']:
                        # Do something.
                        break
                    else:
                        # Do something else.
        else:
            form = BookmarkSaveForm()
        return render_to_response('save_bookmark_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't think of Django views as being in any way special. **It's just Python**. As such, you can have whatever functions you like in views.py. The only limitation is that views themselves have to take a request object and return a subclass of `HttpResponse`. Other than that, you can do what you like in that module, including having functions, classes or constants that are used by your views.

If you have a lot of utility functions, you may want to consider extracting them into eg a `lib.py` in your app directory for the sake of tidiness. But there's no need to do that if you've just got one or two.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. it's fine to have functions in `views.py` that are not views - (I do this all the time). This is particularly appropriate if the function is only for use within that module (i.e. by views in that `views.py`), or by just a single view function.

You could always make it a [private function](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/private_functions.html) if you're worried about exposing it to the outside world. Also, try avoid giving it a parameter called `request`, I tend to subconsciously parse functions which take a request as view functions when reading code.